# Eliminar elemento en C++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente problema, debo eliminar un producto, el cual se mandará a buscar y se eliminará toda su información siguiente:
− Código
− Nombre
− Descripción
− Presentación
− Precio

*Por ejemplo, si ingreso un producto con el código 467, el nombre de Leche, como descripción lácteos, la presentación seria caja y el precio 17...al buscar el producto "leche" para eliminarlo, debe eliminar toda su información...*

Esto es lo que llevo de momento, **Sólo necesito ayuda en la parte de la eliminación**

**Ignoren esto**: antes de enviar mi pregunta me está diciendo que es mayormente código y que debo seguir agregando descripción, así que eso es lo que hago jajaja

````
#include <string>
#include <vector>
 
using namespace std;
 
struct Producto
{
    int codigo;
    string nombre;
    string descripcion;
    string presentacion;
    float precio;
};
 
void menu();
void ingresar(vector<Producto> &v);
void modificar(vector<Producto> &v, int i);
int buscar(vector<Producto> v, int cod);
void mostrar(vector<Producto> v, int i);
void eliminar(vector<Producto> &v);
 
int main()
{
    int cod, id;
    char opcion;
    vector<Producto> productos;
 
    do {
        menu();
        cin >> opcion;
 
        switch(opcion)
        {
            case '1':
                ingresar(productos);
                break;
 
            case '2':
                cout << "\nCodigo a modificar: "; cin >> cod;
                id = buscar(productos, cod);
 
                if (id != -1)
                {
                    mostrar(productos, id);
                    modificar(productos, id);
                }
                else
                    cout << "\n\nPRODUCTO NO ENCONTRADO" << endl;
                break;
 
            case '3':
                cout << "\nCodigo a buscar: "; cin >> cod;
                id = buscar(productos, cod);
 
                if (id != -1)
                    mostrar(productos, id);
                else
                    cout << "\n\nPRODUCTO NO ENCONTRADO" << endl;
                break;
 
            case '4':
                eliminar(productos);
                break;
 
            case '5':
                cout << "\n\nFIN DEL PROGRAMA" << endl;
                break;
 
            default:
                cout << "\n\nOPCION NO VALIDA" << endl;
                break;
        }
 
    } while (opcion != '5');
 
    return 0;
}
 
void menu()
{
    cout << "\n        MENU"
         << "\n======================"
         << "\n1.- Ingrear Producto"
         << "\n2.- Modificar Producto"
         << "\n3.- Buscar Producto"
         << "\n4.- Eliminar Producto"
         << "\n5.- Salir"
         << "\n======================"
         << "\nOPCION (1-5): ";
}
 
void ingresar(vector<Producto> &v)
{
    Producto p;
 
    cout << "\nNuevo Producto:\n";
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    cout << "Codigo: "; cin >> p.codigo;
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    cout << "Nombre: "; getline(cin, p.nombre);
    cout << "Descripcion: "; getline(cin, p.descripcion);
    cout << "Presentacion: "; getline(cin, p.presentacion);
    cout << "Precio: "; cin >> p.precio;
 
    v.push_back(p);
}
 
void modificar(vector<Producto> &v, int i)
{
    cout << endl;
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    cout << "Nuevo Nombre: "; getline(cin, v[i].nombre);
    cout << "Nueva Descripcion: "; getline(cin, v[i].descripcion);
    cout << "Nueva Presentacion: "; getline(cin, v[i].presentacion);
    cout << "Nuevo Precio: "; cin >> v[i].precio;
}
 
int buscar(vector<Producto> v, int cod)
{
    int pos = 0;
 
    while (pos < v.size() && v[pos].codigo != cod)
        pos++;
 
    if (pos >= v.size())
        pos = -1;
 
    return pos;
}
 
void mostrar(vector<Producto> v, int i)
{
    cout << "\nNombre: " << v[i].nombre
         << "\nDescripcion: " << v[i].descripcion
         << "\nPresentacion: " << v[i].presentacion
         << "\nPrecio: " << v[i].precio
         << endl;
}
 
void eliminar(vector<Producto> &v)
{
 }```
````

Answer (score 1):

La clase `vector` funciona con iteradores. Un iterador no es más que un objeto que sabe *moverse* a través de la estructura del contenedor, lo que permite recorrer sus elementos.

Lo que tienes que hacer es posicionar un iterador sobre el elemento a eliminar:

```
void eliminar(vector<Producto> &v)
{
    cout << "\nCódigo a eliminar: ";
    cin >> codigo;
    int posicion = buscar(v, codigo);
    if (posicion >= 0)
    {
        std::vector<Producto>::iterator it = std::next(v.begin(), posicion);
        v.erase(it);
    }
}
```

`std::next` es una función que mueve el iterador `n` posiciones a través de la lista. También se podría haber hecho manualmente, pero no es la opción recomendable:

```
void eliminar(vector<Producto> &v)
{
    cout << "\nCódigo a eliminar: ";
    cin >> codigo;
    int posicion = buscar(v, codigo);
    if (posicion >= 0)
    {
        std::vector<Producto>::iterator it = v.begin();
        while( posicion-- )
        {
            ++it;
        }
        v.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Volviendo al código inicial, desde C++11 (estándar que data del 2011), es posible dejar el código así:

```
void eliminar(vector<Producto> &v)
{
    cout << "\nCódigo a eliminar: ";
    cin >> codigo;
    int posicion = buscar(v, codigo);
    if (posicion >= 0)
    {
        auto it = std::next(v.begin(), posicion);
        v.erase(it);
    }
}
```

`auto` hace al compilador responsable de elegir el mejor tipo para `it`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Debería ser simple, primero pedir que el usuario ingrese el código. Con ese código buscar el producto en el vector, eliminar el producto y la referencia del vector.

```
void eliminar(vector<Producto> &v)
{
    cout << "\nCódigo a eliminar: ";
    cin >> codigo;
    int posicion = buscar(v, codigo);
    if (posicion >= 0) {
        v.erase(posicion);
    }
}
```